# Visual C# Loading Image from resource

Tags: c#

I cant seem to load an image from my resource folder, the image changes depending on the combo box value

```
if(cmbProduct.Text == "T-Shirt, Black, The Big Day Out" || 
   cmbProduct.Text == "T-Shirt, Black, V-Vestival" || 
   cmbProduct.Text == "T-Shirt, Black, Sound Relief")
{
    picProduct.Visible = true;
    picProduct.Image = Image.FromFile("T-Shirt, Black.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: If you add it to your Resource.resx file you can access it like `Properties.Resources.<yourimage>`

Comment: `picProduct.Image = Properties.Resources.("T-Shirt, Black.jpeg");` doesnt seem to work

Comment: it does not take a string. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhS2GZk8ejo

Comment: Let intellisense do its magic and suggest you the name you should type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Felix D was mention is adding your image to resource as "existing file". Though, the name of "*T-Shirt, Black.jpeg*" will be rename to `T_Shirt__Black` in the resource.

Below are what you might want to achieve I believe:-

```
private void cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            picProduct.Visible = false;
            picProduct.InitialImage = null;
            if (cmbProduct.Text == "T-Shirt, Black, The Big Day Out" || cmbProduct.Text == "T-Shirt, Black, V-Vestival" || cmbProduct.Text == "T-Shirt, Black, Sound Relief")
            {
                picProduct.Visible = true;
                picProduct.Image = Properties.Resources.T_Shirt__Black;
            }
        }
```

In Solution Explorer, right click your **projectName** --> **Properties** --> Add Existing File... and pick the file that you want. At insertion, Visual Studio will automatically rename the resource image replacing space, dash, comma with underscore so when you write `Properties.Resources.`, IntelliSense will show you what the properties have.

[image]

[image]